# Editing an existing tableview row to enter new text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview which is populated by entering data in a textfield and clicking an add button.

I have implemented the delete and reorder functions to the tableview by setting the tableview's editing mode to YES. This works on clicking the edit button.

Now I want to be able to select a row, display the text from the selected row in the textfield, edit that text and add the new text to the same row index. What is the best way to do it.

**Update:**
I am using didSelectRowAtIndexPath to select the row and updating the text in the selected row in the addEditButton method as suggested in the answer. I am changing the Add Ingredient button to Update when the row is selected.

But when I click on the Update button, the app crashes. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Can someone suggest with a code, how can I achieve the edit functionality?

Here is my new code :

```
//Edit a row in the tableview
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath
{
    [iTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath animated:NO];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.ingredientsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath];
    if (cell.selected) {
        //change the text of the add indredient button to Update
        [self.addUpdateButton setTitle:@"Update" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //show the cancel button
        [self.cancelUpdateButton setHidden:NO];

        self.ingredientTextField.text = self.ingredientItems[iIndexPath.row];
        //self.recipeIndex = iIndexPath.row;
        self.selectedCellIndexPath = iIndexPath;

    }
}
//Add text in tableview
- (IBAction)addIngredient:(id)sender
{
    //Add ingredients
    if ([self.addUpdateButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString: @"Add Ingredient"]) {
        if ([self.ingredientTextField.text length] != 0) {
            //when button clicked add the text to the ingredientItems
            [self.ingredientItems addObject:self.ingredientTextField.text];
            [self.ingredientsTableView reloadData];
            self.ingredientTextField.text = @"";
            [self.ingredientTextField resignFirstResponder];
        }
        //Update the selected row ingredient
    } else if ([self.addUpdateButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Update"])
               {
                   //the row selected should be updated with the new text
                   //remove the previous object from the array and add the new one on the same index and the same row
                   [self.ingredientItems removeObject:self.selectedCellIndexPath];
                   [self.ingredientItems addObject:self.ingredientTextField.text];

                   [self.ingredientsTableView beginUpdates];
                   [self.ingredientsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                   [self.ingredientsTableView endUpdates];
               }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the view controller

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can achieve this:

**Step 1:** Once cell is tapped load the text field with the cell recipe text. Save the cell index & index path.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    [iTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:iIndexPath animated:NO];

    self.ingredientTextField.text = self.ingredientItems[iIndexPath.row];
    self.selectedCellIndexPath = iIndexPath;
}
```

**Step 2:** Update the text in cell and update the model.
 I am assuming here you can use `self.selectedCellIndexPath.row` to update `self.ingredientItems`.

**Step 3:** Reload the affected cell now.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: How and where do you define recipeIndex and selectedCellIndexPath? Also, is the code in Step 3 written in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Thanks.

Comment: recipie index is just either a integer or nsnumber and slelctedcellIndexpath is an indexpath . You can define them in your viewdidload

Comment: I have taken off recipeIndex because we can use selectedCellIndexPath.row to fetch the array object. This will be a class level property.